# Warn the user about the lack of volume information

Tags: pine-script, volume

For some charts, the vendor does not provide volume information.
How can I detect it from the first bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
var bool noVolume = false

if na(volume) and barstate.isfirst
    noVolume := true

if noVolume == false
    // do normal calcs with volume
else if noVolume == true
    // do something else when no volume
```